# Do not wait for page to finish loading in selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

As the title states, I'm trying to create a script which opens multiple tabs in a browser. At the moment the script seems to wait until each page has finished loading before moving on to a new tab. Is there a way to move on without waiting for the page to load. It seems to be hard to find relevant information online.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'selenium-webdriver'

file = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
file.each do |host|
    driver.get(host)
    driver.execute_script( "window.open()" )
    driver.switch_to.window( driver.window_handles.last )
end
```

Comment: I think I have an Answer for you. Can you consider Accepting an Answer through Java bindings? You may need to convert it into Ruby bindings. Thanks

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I can provide you an Answer through `Selenium-Java`. You have to convert it into `Selenium-Ruby`. Would that work for you?